Unable to log in and receive an error message Ubuntu 24.04 LTS system
This is an Ubuntu 24.04 LTS system. I receive this message after booting and I am unable to login.
[ 909.2721981] audit: kauditd hold queue overflow
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
